# Troubles with nginx reverse proxy configuration for serving multiple Django app docker containers

Tags: python, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have troubles with Nginx reverse proxy configuration

I have a few docker containers with Django websites on my server and
I'm trying to serve them using jwilder/nginx-proxy.

What am I doing wrong?

========Project Structure========

nginx-proxy

- docker-compose.yml

django_project_A

- src

  - django files(db.sqlite3 main_app manage.py django_project_A static)
- docker-compose.yml
- Dockerfile
- config

  - nginx

    - nginx.conf

django_project_B

... same as django_project_A

===============nginx-proxy docker-compose.yml==================

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

===============django_project_A docker-compose.yml==================

```
version: '2'  
services:  
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx_django_project_A
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src      
      - ./src/static:/static
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: django_project_A
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && gunicorn django_project_A.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - ./src/static:/static
    expose:
      - "8000"

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

===============django_project_A nginx.conf==================

```
upstream web {  
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}

server {  
  location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /static/;        
    }
  location / {
        proxy_pass http://web/;
    }

  listen 8000;
  server_name site.com;
}
```

===============django_project_A Dockerfile==================

```
FROM python:3.5  
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1  
RUN mkdir /config  
ADD /config/requirements.txt /config/  
RUN pip install -r /config/requirements.txt  
RUN mkdir /src;  
WORKDIR /src
```

Answer (score 0):

Configuration seems fine, to start with check the ports and connectivity.

From web container check if you can `telnet` on 127.0.0.1:8000 and also from nginx container check if you can ping `web`. If ping to `web` is successful, try telnet web:8000.

If it all works, on `host` try to telnet on `host:80` because it may be firewall on host that is blocking incoming traffic.

Answer (score 0):

The "nginx-proxy docker-compose.yml" will be the center of the configuration, so you can try enabling the communication of networks between nginx and project A and B. You can do that by trying something like in your "nginx-proxy docker-compose.yml" :

```
networks:
  nginx:
  name: nginx
  ipam:
    driver: default

django_project_A:
   external: true

django_project_B:
   external: true
```